# Is there an Atom keyboard shortcut or package that will allow me to navigate to each misspelled word?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor, spell-checking

I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut to jump to each instance of a misspelled word in a plaintext Atom file, so I can fix each one with the built-in spell-check in one session as opposed to manually navigating the cursor to each one via keyboard or mouse.